# Change the menu actionLayout value?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, android-navigationview, android-drawer

I have a navigation drawer and I can change font, color etc.. by accessing the `navigationView.getHeaderView(0);` and

```
Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem mi = m.getItem(index);
```

and then I'm able to play with items in drawer.

But in my case I have a text view that is another layout:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_wallet"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_balnce"
        android:title="@string/my_wallet"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/wallet_value"/>
```

In my wallet_value `layout` I have a textView which I need to change its value, here in the image below:

[image]

How I can get this layout and change it?

Answer (score 6):

Fixed with below code :-

```
 Menu menuView = navigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuViewItem = menuView.getItem(4);
TextView walletValue =  menuViewItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.walletValue);
```

Comment: In order to access the menu item, you can do also like this: "menuView.findItem(R.id.nav_wallet)".

Comment: This answer it was good like the pest! Good much!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution in **Kotlin** would be:

```
val menuViewItem = navigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_wallet)
val txtWalletVal = menuViewItem.actionView.walletValue
txtWalletVal.text = "-150"
```

I've used *findItem()* instead of *getItem()* in order to have more flexibility when adding new menu items.

Comment: Hi I want to set the menu custom layout to the left|start how can I do that?. I want -150 where `My Wallet` is written.